Strongest lower bound from averaging argument for probability $\geq 1-p$?
I am reading a research paper where multiple times the authors use the following, which they claim follows from an averaging argument.
Claim: Suppose $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are two finite domains. Suppose $A(x,y)$ is a probabilistic Turing machine such that for some $p<1$,
$$\mathrm{Pr}_{x \in \mathcal{X}, y \in \mathcal{Y}} [A(x,y)=1] \geq 1-p.$$
Then,
$$\mathrm{Pr}_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \left[\mathrm{Pr}_{ y \in \mathcal{Y}}[A(x,y)=1] \geq 1-\sqrt{p}\right] \geq 1-\sqrt{p}.$$
I am unable to see why such a strong bound follows from an averaging argument. I am convinced for example that the following weaker statement follows from averaging:
$$\mathrm{Pr}_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \left[\mathrm{Pr}_{ y \in \mathcal{Y}}[A(x,y)=1] \geq \frac{1-p}{2}\right] \geq \frac{1-p}{2}.$$
It will be very helpful if you can provide a proof that the stronger claim is true. If it is not, I would like to know what is the best bound of the form $\mathrm{Pr}_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \left[\mathrm{Pr}_{ y \in \mathcal{Y}}[A(x,y)=1] \geq c\right] \geq c$ that can be obtained in the above scenario.

This is not a research-level question, and should have been asked at https://cs.stackexchange.com . The bound with $c=1-\sqrt p$ is indeed correct by trivial computation: putting $q=\Pr_x[\Pr_y[A(x,y)=1]\ge1-\sqrt p]$, we have $1-p\le\Pr_{x,y}[A(x,y)=1]\le q+(1-q)(1-\sqrt p)=1-(1-q)\sqrt p$, thus $q\ge1-\sqrt p$.

Sorry, I was not aware that such questions should have been posted at cs.stackexchange. Thanks for your answer, the proof is clear to me now.
